# Local library in Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

does anyone know how to include local or personal library to pipeline ? So I have a block of code that I wanted to be included in each pipeline and instead of pasting that part of code in pipeline, I would like to read it from file on my machine.

Is it possible to include that in start to just read a file with your functions inside ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ ? Or is it something else you're asking?

Comment: It needs to be stored somewhere to be retrieved and then loaded. From my experience (and the documentation provided above), you cannot just load libraries without retrieval.

Comment: Sounds like [JENKINS-42079](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42079).

Answer (score 0):

You can execute it as script if it is available in your Jenkins instance/slave node (based on where you are running it)

```
result = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "path to script file")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for suggestion. I would like to load this script before pipeline tag starts. I have this groovy script to document log file and like I said I have it before pipeline tag starts.